# DevExpress checkbox tree view search error

Tags: javascript, devextreme

I have implemented tree view with checkbox. My data is plain data. I have also enabled search for the tree view.
My sample code can be found @ https://codepen.io/ajaybhasy/pen/MrKEMg

```
$("#selection-treeview").dxTreeView({
items: products,
width: 320,
showCheckBoxesMode: "selectAll",
dataStructure: "plain",
keyExpr: "AttributeId",
parentIdExpr: "ParentAttributeId",
displayExpr: "AttributeName",
searchExpr: "AttributeName",
searchEnabled: true,
selectNodesRecursive: false
});
});
```

These are my settings for the dxTreeview.
The issue is that when I search the following things happen

1. All the Parent elements which are checked becomes unchecked.
2. All the nodes become expanded.

I have set **selectNodesRecursive as false**, because if I make it true when any of the child element is checked the parent also becomes checked during the initial loading which is not acceptable in my case.
 Is this the default behaviour or am I missing something here?

Comment: FYI: There is the same [issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/DevExtreme/issues/2284) on GitHub.